# pointing drupal to a subfolders using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

In my shared hosting root, i have 2 folders main & demo. The main contains the drupal 7 files for the main website and the demo contains the demo version of this website. What i want to do is when i call www.domain.com or domain.com it should get the contents from the main folder and when i call demo.domain.com or www.demo.domain.com (subdomain) i will be able to get the demo version of this website. I have made an .htaccess file as shown below and placed it in the root folder for redirection. The issue is when i call the www.domain.com or domain.com is opening the home page but all the other links(www.domain.com/page) will not work. The only way it works will be when i give the url as www.domain.com/main/page. I have changed the `base_url` also to 'www.domain.com', i dont have much of an idea with htaccess file. please assisnt me with this issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+main/
RewriteRule ^main/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+demo/
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*)$ http://demo.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(main|demo)/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?demo\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, i figured it out. This .htaccess solved my issue.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ main/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* main/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* main/index.php?q=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Now i am able to put the drupal files in a subfolder named main and was able to access the subdomain demo.subdomain from the browser. Also need to change the `$base_url` in `settings.php` to `$base_url='www.domain.com'` . A really big thanks to kahthong.com  for this valuable [post](http://kahthong.com/2011/05/how-serve-drupal-sub-directory-web-root-0).

Answer (score 0):

This should ideally be added to your apache config in terms of both best practice and performance, and look along the lines of:

```
#example demo.domain.com.conf
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName demo.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/demo.domain.com/htdocs
 <Directory /var/www/demo.domain.com/htdocs>
    Options All
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</virtualhost>

#example domain.conf
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/htdocs
 <Directory /var/www/domain.com/htdocs>
    Options All
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
</virtualhost>
```

however if this isn't an option and your control is limited to .htaccess in your root web folder, you can proxy a subdomain to the demo folder by adding the following:

```
#Add to .htaccess in web root under IfModule block:
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^demo\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/demo/$1 [P]
```

This is assuming that you have drupal core in both your main site folder and demo.

Comment: the issue is with the main website, whatever link i click will be like www.domain.com/page which is exactly what i am looking for but the link will give this error 'The requested page "/page" could not be found.'. to get the page i have to manually make the link to www.domain.com/main/page.